# Integral to express the density of states in the microcanonical ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, dirac-delta-distributions, density-of-states

I was exploring a problem in the microcanonic ensemble, when we have to systems that exhange heat and in the solutions I came across two possible ways to express the total density of states.
$D(E)= \int(d\mu*\delta(E-E1-E2)$ being $d\mu$ over the phase space and delta is to restrain the energy to E=E1+E2, which I understand .
and the other expression is

$D(E)= \int(dE1dE2D(E1)D(E2)$

And exists similar expressions to the number of states, which is also very confusing because books like kardar define number of states just like density of states,which I think it is because in the thermodynamic limit they are the same, but seeing it for the first time it is pretty confusing to define number of states and density of states.
But my main question is, what is the difference between integraging over energy and over the phase space. Why when integraging over energy is not necessary the delta function?

Comment: I guess you missed something in the integrals you wrote compared to your source (or your source is sloppy). My guess would be that the energy constraint is encoded in the integration there and the second differential is just a typo or so. $D(E) = \int_0^E dE_1 D(E_1) D(E - E_1)$ would make sense.

Could you give more context from your source to clarify this?

Comment: I think is possible to write it both ways, at least according to my teacher in college. Kardar in his book does it with number of states. You can go from one to another with some algebra. But my question is more related to the integral, to be more precise I dont get the meaning of the second integral with integration over energy, why it doesnt require a delta function to restrain energy , because integraging over phase space does? I am sorry if i am expressing myself very well, it just I trying to process the information that I dont get very well.

Comment: The second integral, as written is either wrong, or incomplete, or uses some non-standard constraint/notation. (For starters, if you have two differentials and only one integration sign, the result will still contain one of the differentials according to the usual rules, furthermore, the right-hand side does not contain a reference to the argument $E$ occurring on the left-hand side).

Comment: Yes, it is incomplete, it has two integrals signs, it is integrating over E1 and E2, and E=E1+E2, I am used to write like that, because my teacher is college writes like this, because he knows we understand. Sorry about that. It is describing the total energy of two systems 1 and 2 once they exchange heat, so you can rewrite E2=E-E1, so it is the same thing, it just written differently. When you change variables from E2 to E-E1 the double integration is just one integration. Using the number of states like in Kardar, I understand, with this expression I dont understand.

Answer (score 1):

The two expressions can be connected as follows.

The density of states of a system is
$$ D(E) = \int d\mu\, \delta\bigl(E - E(\mu)\bigr) $$
where $\mu$ are the phase-space coordinates.

Now, when connecting two such systems, we get (the new phase space is the product of the original phase spaces, the energies of the subsystems only depend on the phase space coordinates in their sector, so $E_\text{total}(\mu_\text{total}) = E(\mu_1) + E(\mu_2)$):
\begin{align*}
 D_\text{total}(E) &= \int d\mu_\text{total}\, \delta\bigl(E-E(\mu_\text{total})\bigr) = \int d\mu_1 \int d\mu_2 \, \delta\bigl(E - E(\mu_1) - E(\mu_2) \bigr) \\
 &= \int dE_1 \int dE_2 \int d\mu_1 \int d\mu_2\, \delta\bigl(E_1 - E(\mu_1) \bigr) \delta\bigl(E_2 - E(\mu_2)\bigr) \delta(E - E_1 - E_2) \\
 &= \int dE_1 \int dE_2 \delta(E - E_1 - E_2) \underbrace{\int d\mu_1 \delta\bigl(E_1 - E(\mu_1)\bigr)}_{= D(E_1)} \underbrace{\int d\mu_2 \delta\bigl(E_2 - E(\mu_2)\bigr)}_{=D(E_2)} \\
 &= \int dE_1 \int dE_2 \, \delta(E - E_1 - E_2) D(E_1) D(E_2) \\
 &= \int dE_1\, D(E_1) D(\underbrace{E - E_1}_{=E_2}).
\end{align*}

So there is no $\delta$ necessary, because it is already used by reducing the two integrations two one integration (and thereby constraining the arguments of $D$).

Comment: than you, i understand now, i am sorry if didnt express myself better, I am learning this for the first time. I think my teacher made a mistake when he was solving the problem, i think he just forgot the delta function. Just one more question, if it isnt too much trouble, why a lot of books express density of states in the same way as number of states, like kardar for example, it is because in thermodynamic limit they are the same?

Comment: We talk about *number* of states when we are dealing with discrete states and *density* of states when we are dealing states that are continuous functions. If $\Omega$ is the number of states with energies from 0 to $E$, the density of states is $\omega(E) = \partial\Omega(E)/\partial E$. If you replace $\Omega$ with *mass* and $E$ with *length*, then $\omega$ is the density of a non-uniform line as a function of the position on the line. If you are new to stat mech it will be easier to start with the discrete case first and then pass to continuous phase space,

Answer (score -1):

I am answering to your main question that what is the meaning of integrating over phase space and energy. By integrating over energy, you get density or say pressure of boson gas, while integrating over phase is for fermion. This is because, in fermion there are no cycles and there is limit of phase space or volume is confined, that gives variable a limit for integration.

In fermions $\varepsilon=\frac{p^2}{2m}$, therefore density of states is, $$D(\varepsilon)\propto \sqrt{\varepsilon}d\varepsilon\sim p^2dp$$In boson $\varepsilon=pc$, therefore density of states is,$$D(\varepsilon)\propto \varepsilon^2d\varepsilon$$

Comment: I am so confused by your answer. Discard what? and i am not talking about fermions. i am really sorry i just dont understand.

Comment: Your main question was, what is difference between integrating with phase space and energy for density of states, so I tried.